# Laravel 7 - How to process all API controllers response data before middleware Closure call?

Tags: php, laravel, api, middleware, laravel-7

I have an API on Laravel 7.0, where all responses are automatically transformed to json by default because of api routes middleware.

The problem is that some of the responses cause the "Malformed UTF-8 Characters" error on JSON Response, so I have to manually process all data before I return it on controller, like this:

```
return FormatString::convertLatin1Utf8($data);
```

It works fine, but now I have to return data this way in every single api method.

I have a middleware to process cryptography on requests in and out, like this:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        //... some processing before request

        $request = $next($request)->original;

        //... some processing after request

        return response()->json($request);
    }
```

I thought of formatting my data on middleware after the request is processed, so I wouldn't have to call FormatString in every method, like this:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        //... some processing before request

        $request = $next($request)->original;

        //... some processing after request
        $request['data'] = FormatString::convertLatin1Utf8($resquest['data']);

        return response()->json($request);
    }
```

But when `$next($request)` is called it tries to process the Json response on the unformatted data and throw the error I'm trying to avoid.

Is there any way to get the request data before Laravel tries to process into Json, without having to always format it on controller return?

Comment: you could probably use some better naming than reusing `$request` there

Comment: Another option might be to create an `ApiController` with a method like `getResponse($data)`, do you conversion in there, and have all your controllers extend that controller calling `return $this->getResponse($data);`

Comment: you seem to be mixing up request and response in your description in your question

Comment: That ApiController method would be basically the same I'm doing now, repeating the same method call in every response instead of formatting all responses in one place.